# Local proxy behind cloudflare tunnel

Tags: dns, proxy, lan, cloudflare

There are a lot of similar questions out there, which look like the same, but they all want actually something different or were never answered, I hope you can help me with that.

I recently bought a domain on cloudflare, added needed DNS records and set-up a dynamic IP change detector on my local server.

My overall setup is like this:

- I have a cloudflared tunnel running on my home server A.
- There is a website hosted on the same server A.
- There is another website hosted on server B in the same LAN, I access this website over a subdomain and cloudlfared setup.
- On server B there is also a squid proxy running.
- Inside my LAN the router assigns addresses to each machine, so from LAN I can access other machines using e.g. `http://serverB.zyxel.box`

The squid proxy is http and uses basic http auth.
Earlier I had a dynamic DNS from no-ip (e.g. `myhome.ddns.net`) and was able to:

1. Connect to my proxy over that ddns
2. Access my LAN machines using `serverB.zyxel.box`

What I want now, is instead of `ddns.net` I want to use my newly bought domain, but I have yet not figured out, how to forward the traffic to that local proxy.

Any help and suggestions are appreciated.

FYI: Server A is a Windows Machine, and I don't want to use nginx.

If this doesn't work, then in general, is there any way to use my domain as a proxy with http auth, so that I can access my LAN machines using `serverA.zyxel.box`?

(I want to be able to do `http_proxy=user:pw@my.domain.com curl http://serverA.zyxel.box/` from outside of my LAN.)